# How to sort lines of a file alphabetically in C?

Tags: c, file, sorting, linked-list

Ok so what I have right now, checks the counts of the words. But I am having trouble trying to sort the words alphabetically.

I'd rather do that then just count the number of which they are.

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 

typedef struct node *node_ptr; 

typedef struct node {
    int count;
    char *word;
    node_ptr next;
} node_t;  

char *words[] = { "hello", "goodbye", "sometimes", "others", "hello", "others", NULL }; 

node_ptr new_node() {
    node_ptr aNode;
    
    aNode = (node_ptr)(malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
    if (aNode) {
        aNode->next = (node_ptr)NULL;
        aNode->word = (char *)NULL;
        aNode->count = 0;
    }
    return aNode;
}

node_ptr add_word(char *word, node_ptr theList) {
    node_ptr currPtr, lastPtr, newPtr;
    int result;
    int found = 0;
    
    currPtr = theList;
    lastPtr = NULL;
    printf("Checking word:%s\n", word);
    
    if (!currPtr) {
        newPtr = new_node();
        if (!newPtr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error. Memory alloc error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newPtr->word = word;
        newPtr->next = currPtr;
        newPtr->count = 1;
        found = 1;
        theList = newPtr;
    }
    while (currPtr && !found) {
        result = strcmp(currPtr->word, word); 
        if (result == 0) {
            currPtr->count += 1;
            found = 1;
        } else
        if (result>0) {
            newPtr = new_node();
            if (!newPtr) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error. Memory alloc error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            newPtr->word = word;
            newPtr->next = currPtr;
            newPtr->count = 1;

            if (lastPtr) {
                lastPtr->next = newPtr;
            } else {
                theList = newPtr;
            }
            found = 1;
        } else {
            lastPtr = currPtr;
            currPtr = currPtr->next;
        }
    }

    if ((!found) && lastPtr) {
        newPtr = new_node();
        if (!newPtr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error. Memory alloc error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        newPtr->word = word;
        newPtr->next = (node_ptr)NULL;
        newPtr->count = 1;
        lastPtr->next = newPtr;
        found = 1;
    }
    return theList; 
}

void printList(node_ptr theList) {
    node_ptr currPtr = theList;
    
    while (currPtr) {
        printf("word: %s\n", currPtr->word);
        printf("count: %d\n", currPtr->count);
        printf("---\n");
        currPtr = currPtr->next; 
    }
}

int main() {
    char **w = words;
    node_ptr theList = (node_ptr)NULL;
    
    printf("Start\n");
    while (*w) {
        theList = add_word(*w, theList);
        w++;
    }
    
    printList(theList);
    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'd also like to instead of reading from an array of words, I'd rather read from a file.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("some.txt", "w");
```

How do I read from a file using my structure I've created and then sort them?

Comment: It is a bad habit to typedef pointers: `typedef struct node *node_ptr;` Hiding pointers does not make them easier to understand or handle, quite to the contrary, it obfuscates your code.

Comment: In `add_word()`, `newPtr->word = word;` is an issue.  Code likely needs to add a copy of the string.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want to do both @WeatherVane .. I'd like to read words from a file and sort them alphabetically!

Comment: Read about `qsort`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the words from a file with `fscanf()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    node_t *theList = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (fp != NULL) {
            char word[100];
            while (fscanf(fp, "%99s", word) == 1) {
                theList = add_word(word, theList);
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    printList(theList);
    printf("OK!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "line" in your code? in the addword function.. where do you initialize that?

Comment: @hiquetj: sorry, it was just a typo, I renamed the local array `word` and forgot that instance.  As you can see, I open the file with `fopen`, read words one by one with `fscanf()` and add them to the list.  Words are separated by any amount of whitespace characters, including linefeeds.

Comment: @hiquetj: did this answer help you?  Do you mind accepting it?